# How to create relation between 2 databases in Django ORM (one unmanaged, and one managed)

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

1. `ciad_db` - MySQL, unmanaged

```
class NormalizedData(models.Model):
    ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, primary_key=True, default='noticketid')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    ticket_source = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    conclusion = models.ForeignKey(DsrConclusions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'normalized_data'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(
                fields=[
                    'status',
                    'ticket_source',
                    'summary',
                ]
            )
        ]
```

2. `default` - sqlite3 , managed

```
class DsrConclusions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    explanation = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    final_breach_conclusion = models.BooleanField(blank=False,null=False)
    last_owner = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        indexes = [
            models.Index(
                fields=[
                    'ticket_number',
                    'explanation',
                    'final_breach_conclusion',
                    'last_owner',
                ]
            )
        ]
```

in `models.py`, `DsrConclusions` comes in before `NormalizedData`

I use a database router because of the 2 databases, which looks like this:

```
class CiadRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in
    the ciadseeweb application
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point all operations on ciadseeweb models to 'ciad_db'
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ciadseeweb':
            return 'ciad_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ciadseeweb':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the 'ciadseeweb' app only appears on the 'other' db
        """
        if db == 'ciad_db':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'ciadseeweb'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'ciadseeweb':
            return False
        return None
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('default', 'ciad_db')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None
```

Since I've added the column after migrations were done (and things are working fine), once I add the column and run `makemigrations`, I get `No changes detected`, which is because `NormalizedData` is unmanaged. I then change that to managed, run `makemigrations` again and I get them to detect the changes. Once I run `migrate` they apply just fine.

When I run the server (which starts-up without errors) and refresh the page where I am rendering `NormalizedData` data into a `django-tables2` with `django_tables2_column_shifter` table.

In order to get data from the `DsrConclusions` model in `tables.py` which renders from the `NormalizedData` model. I am using `dsr_review = tables.Column(verbose_name='DSR SLA', accessor='dsrconclusions.final_breach_conclusion')`, as specified in the `django-tables2` documentation.

I end up getting:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'normalized_data.conclusion_id' in 'field list'")`

I am stuck. What am I doing wrong?! Is this even possible?

Environment

```
Package Name    Version
Django      2.2
Python      3.7.2
Crispy_Forms    1.7.2
Debug Toolbar   1.11
Django_Tables2  2.0.6
Django_Tables2_Column_Shifter   0.5.2
```

Comment: Have you verified that the field `conclusion_id` is present in the database? I can't speak specifically to this problem, but per Django docs, this sort of configuration is not specifically supported - although it does say that it can be faked using SQLite (however it doesn't elaborate as to whether that faking requires additional work) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations

Comment: Thanks, @jimijimjim! I've read somewhere that the ```_id``` is automatically appended to the ForeignKey's field name, by Django's ORM if one doesn't specifically specify the field's name (via some attribute) - so this is expected. However the limitation from the docs seems I hit a wall here...Would there be any alternative to the one mentioned in the docs?

Comment: You can use the `db_column` to make sure that the ORM has the correct name for `conclusion` in the database. `conclusion = models.ForeignKey(DsrConclusions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, db_column='something')`. The error you're getting suggests that the ORM is looking for column `conclusion_id` and not finding it

Comment: With ```conclusion = models.ForeignKey(DsrConclusions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, db_column='concl')``` I get ```django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'normalized_data.concl' in 'field list'")```, which is essentially the same as the previous error. Was worth trying.